# Setting up Drupal and Wordpress under a single document root

Tags: apache, wordpress, drupal, .htaccess, hosting

I have a hosting account which provides me a folder to publish my files for my domain (say www.example.com). I have set up Drupal for www.example.com with .htaccess at the top folder to enable clean-urls for the Drupal installation. Now I want to have a Wordpress installation under www.example.com/blog/ and have clean URLs for that blog. But while using .htaccess it is not working ok as the .htaccess at the top folder will override the sub-folder one. How to achieve what I intend to?

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on the exact content of your respective .htaccess files.

One workaround is to add a `RewriteCond` to the head of the main .htaccess file that, if the request URI matches the sub-directory, stops parsing:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

this should lead to the blog URLs being parsed properly, based on the rules specified there.